# Unexpected C++ Vector Behavior

Tags: c++, vector

For some reason I'm having a discrepancy between the empty() vector operator and what is in the vector.

```
if(myvector.empty())cout<<"My Vector is empty\n";
cout<<myvector.front()<<endl;
cout<<myvector[0]<<endl;
print(myvector);
```

`print()` is my function that simply takes a vector input and prints the vector.

For some reason, my vector, which shouldn't be empty returns empty for `myvector.empty()`, however it returns the first (and expected) value for `myvector.front()` and `myvector[0]`, however when printing the entire vector, no contents are printed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please form an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If a vector is empty, it is against its contract to call `front` or use `operator[]`.

Comment: Violating that contract leads to Undefined Behavior, which may very well include such behavior as a vector appearing to be both empty and non-empty. There is no limitation to the weirdness you can get from Undefined Behavior.

Comment: My money is on "I wrote myvector[0] = 5; and that works..."

Answer (score 2):

When vector is empty, you need to let your if statement switch to cout only otherwise the behavior is undefined.

a simple and quick fix is

```
if(myvector.empty()) 
{
    cout<<"My Vector is empty\n";
}
else 
{
    cout<<myvector.front()<<endl;
    cout<<myvector[0]<<endl;
    print(myvector);
}
```

Comment: I take it the real question pertains to *which shouldn't be empty*, but the OP hasn't shown anything to that end, so I don't know how we're supposed to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you used `reserve` to allocate space for your vector but then added elements with `operator[]` rather than `insert` or `push_back`.

In order to actually ADD an element to the vector you need to use one of those methods that does so, not just accessing elements with `[]`. This is why your vector `empty` call is true. By pure random chance the memory you've allocated does have the values you expect.